# How to detect when select menu is active with vanillajs

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I have multiple select menus and for all of them, I want to add the same functionality. I want to change the arrow position based on if the select drop down menu is active or not. Keep the down arrow if it is not active and change the arrow to up side if the select menu is active. For that, I have below js code but, it did not work, I tried using active() method but, got this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: selectMenus[i].active is not a function
```

Below is code that i tried

```
 const selectMenus = document.getElementsByClassName('select-menu');
    for (let i = 0; i < selectMenus.length; i++) {
        selectMenus[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            if (selectMenus[i].active()) {
                console.log("yeeeee")
            }
            selectMenus[i].style.backgroundImage = `url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='%23a0aec0'%3e%3cpath d='M15.3 9.3a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 1.4l-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.4 0l-4-4a1 1 0 0 1 1.4-1.4l3.3 3.29 3.3-3.3z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e")`;
        });
    }
```

Now, the question is, how do I change the direction of the arrow based on the active status of select menu drop down? Can it be done in css? I tried to apply `select-menu:focus` pseudo selector but, that does not work the way I want it to work. That way, the direction of arrow only changes when I click outside of the select menu. So, Initially it is down direction arrow, when click select menu, it is changed to up direction and when clicked again, the arrow direction stays up direction even the drop down menu is not active. I guess that makes sense because the select menu is still on focus state.

The css for select menu

```
.select-menu {
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='%23a0aec0'%3e%3cpath d='M15.3 9.3a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 1.4l-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.4 0l-4-4a1 1 0 0 1 1.4-1.4l3.3 3.29 3.3-3.3z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.select-menu:focus {
    background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-up" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 5.707l-5.646 5.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6z"/></svg>');
}
```

The html

```
<select name="options[20][year]" id="options_20_year" class="select-menu product-custom-option admin__control-select datetime-picker mr-1 required last:mr-0" title="" data-role="calendar-dropdown" data-calendar-role="year" data-canvas-element="date_year" data-selector="options[20][year]" x-on:input="updateCertificateCanvas()" x-on:change="updateCustomOptionValue($dispatch, 'year', $event.target)" data-validate="{&quot;datetime-validation&quot;: true}">
<option value="">-</option><option value="1900">1900</option><option value="1901">1901</option><option value="1902">1902</option><option value="1903">1903</option><option value="1904">1904</option><option value="1905">1905</option><option value="1906">1906</option><option value="1907">1907</option><option value="1908">1908</option><option value="1909">1909</option><option value="1910">1910</option><option value="1911">1911</option><option value="1912">1912</option><option value="1913">1913</option><option value="1914">1914</option><option value="1915">1915</option><option value="1916">1916</option><option value="1917">1917</option><option value="1918">1918</option><option value="1919">1919</option><option value="1920">1920</option><option value="1921">1921</option><option value="1922">1922</option><option value="1923">1923</option><option value="1924">1924</option><option value="1925">1925</option><option value="1926">1926</option><option value="1927">1927</option><option value="1928">1928</option><option value="1929">1929</option><option value="1930">1930</option><option value="1931">1931</option><option value="1932">1932</option><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="1936">1936</option><option value="1937">1937</option><option value="1938">1938</option><option value="1939">1939</option><option value="1940">1940</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1961">1961</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2011">2011</option><option value="2012">2012</option><option value="2013">2013</option><option value="2014">2014</option><option value="2015">2015</option><option value="2016">2016</option><option value="2017">2017</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2022" selected="selected">2022</option>
</select>

<select name="options[20][month]" id="options_20_month" class="select-menu product-custom-option admin__control-select datetime-picker mr-1 required last:mr-0" title="" data-role="calendar-dropdown" data-calendar-role="month" data-canvas-element="date_month" data-selector="options[20][month]" x-on:input="updateCertificateCanvas()" x-on:change="updateCustomOptionValue($dispatch, 'month', $event.target)" data-validate="{&quot;datetime-validation&quot;: true}">
<option value="">-</option><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2">Feb</option><option value="3">Mar</option><option value="4">Apr</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">Jun</option><option value="7">Jul</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12" selected="selected">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post your html and css too please?

Comment: maybe there's something helpful I can say... if you try to play with all the pseudo selectors available for the select element, you'll see that the closest one for your goal is `:focus`. The element will gain that state when having the focus of course, but you won't be granted that the dropdown options will be shown. Unfortunately that's handled by the OS and it's not business of the browser thus why there's no css control on some of its details including styling options...

Comment: So the only safe option I have is doing your own dropdown with divs controlling its appearence on every plarform the way you wish it to be and so controlling its internal events with the biggest granularity. Otherwise also in js it's a huge game of illusions that I'm quite sure doesn't cover every single case. For example the click event is not 100% of how to open the dropdown. Also the change event wouldn't be enough because it occurs after the option got chosen. Maybe a combination of the right event (focus for exmpl) and checking if the option are shown but I've not that ready in my pockets

Comment: don't forget that if you use the tab key you'll move the focus on each input control (and you can control the sequence with attribute `tabindex`) and the :focus event again won't be enough as a trigger to style the dropdown since the options won't be showing in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `focus` eventListener to check if an input element is active.

```
  select.addEventListener('focus', e=>{
    console.log('is focused/active');
  })
```

For your style toggling task you can trigger a `blur()` event after selecting an option.

```js
let selects = document.querySelectorAll("select");
selects.forEach((select) => {
  let hasFocus = false;
  select.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (hasFocus) {
      e.currentTarget.blur();
      hasFocus = false;
    } else {
      hasFocus = true;
    }
  });

  select.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    e.currentTarget.blur();
  });
});
```

```css
select {
  appearance: none;
  background: none;
  width: 25%
}

.select-menu {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 24 24' fill='%23a0aec0'%3e%3cpath d='M15.3 9.3a1 1 0 0 1 1.4 1.4l-4 4a1 1 0 0 1-1.4 0l-4-4a1 1 0 0 1 1.4-1.4l3.3 3.29 3.3-3.3z'/%3e%3c/svg%3e");
}

.select-menu:focus {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-chevron-up" viewBox="0 0 16 16"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M7.646 4.646a.5.5 0 0 1 .708 0l6 6a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708L8 5.707l-5.646 5.647a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l6-6z"/></svg>');
}
```

```html
<select name="options[20][year]" id="options_20_year" class="select-menu product-custom-option admin__control-select datetime-picker mr-1 required last:mr-0" title="" data-role="calendar-dropdown" data-calendar-role="year" data-canvas-element="date_year"
  data-selector="options[20][year]" x-on:input="updateCertificateCanvas()" x-on:change="updateCustomOptionValue($dispatch, 'year', $event.target)" data-validate="{&quot;datetime-validation&quot;: true}">
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2006">2006</option>
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2015">2015</option>
  <option value="2016">2016</option>
  <option value="2017">2017</option>
  <option value="2018">2018</option>
  <option value="2019">2019</option>
  <option value="2020">2020</option>
  <option value="2021">2021</option>
  <option value="2022" selected="selected">2022</option>
</select>

<select name="options[20][month]" id="options_20_month" class="select-menu product-custom-option admin__control-select datetime-picker mr-1 required last:mr-0" title="" data-role="calendar-dropdown" data-calendar-role="month" data-canvas-element="date_month"
  data-selector="options[20][month]" x-on:input="updateCertificateCanvas()" x-on:change="updateCustomOptionValue($dispatch, 'month', $event.target)" data-validate="{&quot;datetime-validation&quot;: true}">
  <option value="">-</option>
  <option value="1">Jan</option>
  <option value="2">Feb</option>
  <option value="3">Mar</option>
  <option value="4">Apr</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="6">Jun</option>
  <option value="7">Jul</option>
  <option value="8">Aug</option>
  <option value="9">Sep</option>
  <option value="10">Oct</option>
  <option value="11">Nov</option>
  <option value="12" selected="selected">Dec</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This seems to be partial solution. It works only when option is selected. I am trying to make it work so, every time the drop down is not active, the arrow position changes to down side. Even when clicking inside the select input.

Comment: You mean something like this? updated snippet

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as I can get it using pure CSS/HTML. I've wrapped the select elements in a wrapper div and used the :focus-within pseudo selector to see if the underlying button has focus. The only clunky bit if you click on the button to close the dropdown the arrow doesn't revert to it's original state. Have a look and see what you think. I've just used unicode characters for the up/down arrows but you could easily replace this with SVG or background images.

```css
.select-container {
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid gray;
  background-color:lightgray;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.select-container::after {
  content: "▲";
  position: absolute;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  right:0;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:1rem;
  background-color:lightgray;
  pointer-events:none;
}

.select-container:focus-within::after {
  content: "▼"
}

.select-container select {
  background:none;
  border:none;
}
```

```html
<div class='select-container'><select name="options[20][year]" id="options_20_year" class="select-menu product-custom-option admin__control-select datetime-picker mr-1 required last:mr-0" title="" data-role="calendar-dropdown" data-calendar-role="year" data-canvas-element="date_year" data-selector="options[20][year]" x-on:input="updateCertificateCanvas()" x-on:change="updateCustomOptionValue($dispatch, 'year', $event.target)" data-validate="{&quot;datetime-validation&quot;: true}">
<option value="">-</option><option value="2018">2018</option><option value="2019">2019</option><option value="2020">2020</option><option value="2021">2021</option><option value="2022" selected="selected">2022</option>
</select>
</div>

<div class='select-container'>
<select name="options[20][month]" id="options_20_month" class="select-menu product-custom-option admin__control-select datetime-picker mr-1 required last:mr-0" title="" data-role="calendar-dropdown" data-calendar-role="month" data-canvas-element="date_month" data-selector="options[20][month]" x-on:input="updateCertificateCanvas()" x-on:change="updateCustomOptionValue($dispatch, 'month', $event.target)" data-validate="{&quot;datetime-validation&quot;: true}">
<option value="">-</option><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2">Feb</option><option value="3">Mar</option><option value="4">Apr</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">Jun</option><option value="7">Jul</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12" selected="selected">Dec</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: It is the same behavior I am getting. You see, when clicking on select menu, the drop down opens and arrow direction changes. That bit is good but, when clicking on the select menu again, the drop down disappears but, the arrow direction stays the same and only changes when clicking out side of select menu